# Remove mail menu from indicator-messages

Tags: indicator, thunderbird, messaging-menu

I'm using popper mail notification, which integrates into the messaging applet, therefore I have no use for the default message indicator entries. Is there a way to hide/remove them?

I already disabled the thunderbird unity integration add-on.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just need to remove the Thunderbird file from `/usr/share/indicators/messages/applications`.

Comment: Already tried it, but no luck.

Comment: @Dinin: what steps did you take? Without the addon and the entry in that folder, there should be nothing there.

Comment: There was a hidden backup of thunderbird in /usr/share/indicators/messages. Removing this solved my problem. THX

Answer (score 5):

/usr/share/indicators/messages/applications/ as explained [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MessagingMenu#API), are just text files containing path to desktop file. You can blacklist them per-user:

```
cp /usr/share/indicators/messages/applications/* ~/.config/indicators/messages/applications-blacklist/
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You might need to reload the message indicator app.
The following works in xfce (xubuntu)

pkill -HUP -f indicator-messages-service